# returning a Vec<f32> from function costs a lot?

Tags: rust, rust-polars

I'm new to Rust and am facing a weird performance issue when returning a Vec from a function to main.

Given this code, elapsed time is 13us on release compile mode.

```
fn main() -> Result<(), ()> {
    // ... Some code for loading data, ends up with:
    let series: ChunkedArray<Float32Type>

    let start = Instant::now();
    let percentiles = [0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0];
    let mut result = Vec::<f32>::with_capacity(percentiles.len());
    for p in percentiles {
        match series.quantile(p as f64, QuantileInterpolOptions::Lower) {
            Ok(v) => result.push(v.unwrap()),
            _ => {}
        }
    }
    let duration = start.elapsed();
    println!("Time elapsed is: {:?}", duration);
    println!("{}",result");
    Ok(())
}
```

> Time elapsed is: 44.484µs

That's cool and all, but as soon as I extract the logic into a different function, the elapsed time becomes around 72ms (!). Note that I added another time measurement inside the `percentile` function, to ensure that its runtime is still super fast.

```
fn main() -> Result<(), ()> {
    // ... Some code for loading data, ends up with:
    let series: ChunkedArray<Float32Type>

    let start = Instant::now();
    let percentiles = percentile(series);
    let duration = start.elapsed();
    println!("Time elapsed is: {:?}", duration);
    println!("{}",result)
    Ok(())
}

pub fn percentile(data: Series) -> Vec<f32> {
    let data = data;

    let start = Instant::now();
    let percentiles = [0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0];
    let mut result = Vec::<f32>::with_capacity(percentiles.len());
    for p in percentiles {
        match data.quantile(p as f64, QuantileInterpolOptions::Lower) {
            Ok(v) => result.push(v.unwrap()),
            _ => {}
        }
    }
    let duration = start.elapsed();
    println!("internal time: {:?}", duration);

    result
}
```

This result in:

> internal time: 13.796µs

> Time elapsed is: 73.91404ms

Running this code version in debug results in about 600ms

I'm super confused. Why it seems like retuning the value from a function costs so much? What am I missing?

edit:
Measured how much is cost to drop `series` in the first and fast version of the code, comes up to 241µs.

edit 2:

Here is the full output

```
mr@Ripper:~/git/me/distributor$ cargo run -r
   Compiling distributor v0.1.0 (/home/or/git/me/distributor)
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 3.03s
     Running `target/release/distributor`
[0.15219125, 0.977695, 0.9928536, 1.0046335, 1.0219395, 552.4709]
Time elapsed is: 44.484µs
mr@Ripper:~/git/me/distributor$ cargo run -r
   Compiling distributor v0.1.0 (/home/or/git/me/distributor)
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 2.76s
     Running `target/release/distributor`
internal time: 13.556µs
Time elapsed is: 73.22045ms
[0.15219125, 0.977695, 0.9928536, 1.0046335, 1.0219395, 552.4709
```

Comment: In your first version, you are not measuring the time it takes for `series` to drop. It might be interesting to consider it to have a better picture of both versions.

Comment: @VincentSavard Thanks for the suggestion. I measured it now and on release it takes 241µs, so the problem isn't there.

Comment: Without knowing what `Series` or `ChunkedArray` are, it's hard to tell what the issue is. As Vincent points out, the two examples do have different behavior regarding dropping, which is likely the culprit.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo You're right. Both `Series` and `ChuckedArray` are Polars types (https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/series/struct.Series.html), similar to what Pandas Series is in Python. 

I added the info about dropping, but as I said, still new to Rust so let me know if there's more info I can add which will help.

Comment: Since your first code never actually does anything with `result`, its possible Rust simply optimized everything away. In contrast, it may not have optimized away the function call. Try printing `result` in both cases and see if there's a change.

Comment: @Schwern Thanks. I printed result in the first code and it raised the elapsed time to 50 microseconds. (compared to 70 miliseconds with the second code)

Comment: @CrispyHoliday I added it as an answer. I'm curious if running the optimized `main` in my answer also takes 13us.

Comment: In your second example, you're measuring the time it takes to print the inner timer value…

Answer (score 0):

Since `result` is never used, Rust has likely optimized the body of your `main` function away. You may be benchmarking this.

```
fn main() -> Result<(), ()> {
    // ... Some code for loading data, ends up with:
    // let series: ChunkedArray<Float32Type>

    let start = Instant::now();

    // let percentiles = [0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0];
    // let mut result = Vec::<f32>::with_capacity(percentiles.len());
    // for p in percentiles {
    //     match series.quantile(p as f64, QuantileInterpolOptions::Lower) {
    //         Ok(v) => result.push(v.unwrap()),
    //         _ => {}
    //     }
    // }

    let duration = start.elapsed();
    println!("Time elapsed is: {:?}", duration);
    Ok(())
}
```

By putting the code into a function, the Rust optimizer may not realize the function call is not necessary, so it's calling the function, doing the work, and throwing out the result.

You can avoid this by doing something with the result, such as passing the results to [`black_box`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/hint/fn.black_box.html).

Comment: Instead of printing you can use [`std::hint::black_box()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/hint/fn.black_box.html), that does nothing except disabling any possible optimization.

Comment: @rodrigo That's really useful, thanks!

Comment: You might be able to help the compiler optimize *away* the function call by making it non-public, and by adding `lto = true` to the `Cargo.toml` for release mode. If the function can't be called by anything else, and full optimizations make it clear it's a one-off call, it may be able to optimize it away equally well in both cases.

Comment: It's my mistake, I do print "result" in both code blocks, I just forgot to mention it (editing the question now). In any case, running your suggested code block takes 50ns. Runnning my code without using `result` takes 14microseconds and with printing `result` takes 44 microseconds.